# Прописная/строчная

Tags: грамматика

Не пойму, с прописной или со строчной писать сочетания: *российская конституция, португальская конституция, португальское государство*?

Answer (score 1):

Со строчной оба слова во всех случаях. Конституция без прилагательного ещё может быть написано с прописной в значении условного имени (не наш случай), остальное - просто непонятно откуда идёт идея. Влияние английского, что ли, или бзик власть имущего чиновника, обожающего заглавную...